# How can i break loop in a watson conversation

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation

When a user inputs an insult on a conversation node, I detect the insult, send the user a message and then send the user, using `continue from`, asking him the question again. If the user types an insult again, I will get a loop. How can break this loop and end the conversation?

Comment: There is an example of counters here: https://sodoherty.com/2016/09/22/using-counters-in-conversation/

Answer (score 0):

Implementing counters solve the problem.